Can the p-adic be countable?
Recently arxiv submitted a new paper (Andrej Bauer, James E. Hanson, The Countable Reals) claiming an incredible theorem that Dedekind reals are not sequence-avoiding, and furthermore obtaining a topos that makes Dedekind reals countable.
However, mainstream constructive $p$-adic implementation, such as Cauchy $p$-adic and HoTT $p$-adic, or just base-$p$ expansion $p$-adic, are uncountable.
I would like to know:

Is there exists a $p$-adic implementation that is not sequence-avoiding?
Is there a topos in infinite-time Turing machines where the $p$-adic is countable?
If so, how many metrically complete can be hold in this topos? Can $\mathbb{Q}_p,\mathbb{C}_p,\Omega_p$ be countable?


$\mathbb{Q}_p$ is always going to be sequence-avoiding. Cantor's diagonal argument is constructive in that context.

$\mathbb{C}_p$ is a good question. I'm not entirely sure what's going on there. On the other hand, it's unclear to me if the construction of $\Omega_p$ even really makes sense constructively. Usually it's built with an ultrapower.

@JamesEHanson I was actually thinking the same thing: there should be a simple theorem based on fundamentals that clears all p-adic families of sequence-avoiding at once. But my brain didn't catch it.

@JamesEHanson Consider a weak problem, what is the "largest" field that satisfies strong triangle inequality that is uncountable in the classical and not sequence-avoiding in the construction?

That's an interesting question but I'm not sure how to approach it.

What might be more correct to ask should be whether $\mathbb{Q}_p$ or $\mathbb{C}_p$ can be subcountable, i.e., an image of a subset of $\mathbb{N}$. $\mathbb{R}$ is not a bijective image of $\mathbb{N}$ even in a constructive setting (modulo countable choice), but $\mathbb{R}$ can be subcountable.
